# indexed_db on.success.add() deprecated - new syntax

Tags: dart

What's the new equivalent syntax for the old "on.success.add()"?

I thought that it was onSuccess.first.then(), however that gives me what appears to be only the first (eg.) record from a select. There is a similar situation with eg. html elements "on.click.add()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSuccess is a stream. If you want to receive more than one element just "listen" for them: onSuccess.listen.